# Can I create a for-loop in R to save images?

Tags: r, image, for-loop

I am trying to run a simple loop consisting of 1) running models and 2) saving plots.
I'll end up running tons of these!

The problem I run into is this. In order to save the plot by the method I'm using, I have to "call" the plot as in:

```
png(file=paste(ImageDirectory,"\\","i0.png",sep=""), width = 1000, height = 500)
i0
dev.off()
```

This is successful.
However, in the loop, the plot is not rendered. Instead, R simply prints the plot name as a character string.

```
# Attempted and Failed Loop
images <- c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", "i8", "i9", "i10", "i11")
for (i in images){
  png(file=paste(ImageDirectory,"\\",i,".png",sep=""), width = 1000, height = 500)
  i
  dev.off()
  print(typeof(i))
}
[1] "character"
```

As a result, the image call results in a blank image.
I know why this happens I think. I've stored the names of the images as text. I've tried:

```
as.data.frame(i)
```

No joy! Apologies if this has been asked and answered, I couldn't find anything on point. This [question](http://[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929127/r-loop-through-complete-script-find-all-plots-generated-and-save-them][1]) gets close, but wasn't successful for me either.

Full code sequence below. Any suggestions would be muy appreciado!

```
#Run Survival Models
survival_model <- Surv(time = df$LOS, event = df$isTermed)
fit1 <- survfit(survival_model ~ rResult, data = df)
i0<-ggsurvplot(fit1, data = df,title=df$Label,legend.title = "Result",legend.labs = c("Not Recommended", "Recommended", "Not Assessed"),pval = TRUE,conf.int = FALSE,palette = c("#C00000","#92D050", "#FFC000"),linetype="solid",ggtheme = theme_classic(),break.time.by=90,xlab = "Time in Days",ylab = "Probability of Retention") 
pvals<-rbind(pvals, list("pvals"=surv_pvalue(fit1)$pval.txt),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

survival_model <- Surv(time = df1$LOS, event = df1$isTermed)
fit1 <- survfit(survival_model ~ rResult, data = df1)
i1<-ggsurvplot(fit1, data = df1,title=df1$Label,legend.title = "Result",legend.labs = c("Not Recommended", "Recommended"),pval = TRUE,conf.int = FALSE,palette = c("#C00000","#92D050", "#FFC000"),linetype="solid",ggtheme = theme_classic(),break.time.by=90,xlab = "Time in Days",ylab = "Probability of Retention") 
pvals<-rbind(pvals, list("pvals"=surv_pvalue(fit1)$pval.txt),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

survival_model <- Surv(time = df2$LOS, event = df2$isTermed)
fit1 <- survfit(survival_model ~ rResult, data = df2)
i2<-ggsurvplot(fit1, data = df2,title=df2$Label,legend.title = "Result",legend.labs = c("Not Recommended", "Recommended", "Not Assessed"),pval = TRUE,conf.int = FALSE,palette = c("#C00000","#92D050", "#FFC000"),linetype="solid",ggtheme = theme_classic(),break.time.by=90,xlab = "Time in Days",ylab = "Probability of Retention") 
pvals<-rbind(pvals, list("pvals"=surv_pvalue(fit1)$pval.txt),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#Save their plots
png(file=paste(ImageDirectory,"\\","i0.png",sep=""), width = 1000, height = 500)
i0
dev.off()

png(file=paste(ImageDirectory,"\\","i1.png",sep=""), width = 1000, height = 500)
i1
dev.off()

png(file=paste(ImageDirectory,"\\","i2.png",sep=""), width = 1000, height = 500)
i2
dev.off()
png(file=paste(ImageDirectory,"\\","i3.png",sep=""), width = 1000, height = 500)


# Attempted and Failed Loop
images <- c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", "i8", "i9", "i10", "i11")
for (i in images){
  png(file=paste(ImageDirectory,"\\",i,".png",sep=""), width = 1000, height = 500)
  i
  dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mainly need `get()`

```
images <- c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", "i8", "i9", "i10", "i11")
for (i in images){
  png(file=paste(ImageDirectory,"\\",i,".png",sep=""), width = 1000, height = 500)
  get(i) ## may have to print, too:. print(get(I))
  dev.off()
}
```

It seems like you would be better off using a `list()` of some sort.

```
l <- mget(ls(pattern = "df"))
lapply(seq_along(l),
    function (i) {

     DF <- l[[i]]
      survival_model <- Surv(time = DF$LOS, event = DF$isTermed)
      fit <- survfit(survival_model ~ rResult, data = DF)

      png(file=paste(ImageDirectory,"\\",images[i],".png",sep=""), width = 1000, height = 500)

      ggsurvplot(fit, data = DF,title=DF$Label,legend.title = "Result",legend.labs = c("Not Recommended", "Recommended"),pval = TRUE,conf.int = FALSE,palette = c("#C00000","#92D050", "#FFC000"),linetype="solid",ggtheme = theme_classic(),break.time.by=90,xlab = "Time in Days",ylab = "Probability of Retention") 

      return("pvals"=surv_pvalue(fit)$pval.txt)
    }
 )
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because I plainly, and now so obviously, needed `get()`. Both @Cole @MacOS are generally correct though in their observation that I would be better off looping over the data frames thereby reducing my code even further. Thank you both!!

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it (because I can't at the moment), but I think it is because

```
i0 <- ggsurvplot(
    fit1,
    data = df,
    title=df$Label, ...)
```

does not return the plot. Instead, you get the data typ character. For example, try

```
typeof("MyName")
```

Move the plot logic into the for loop. This would require that save your data frames into a list and loop over this instead. For exmpale

```
my.dfs <- list(
  df.name.one = df.name.one,
  df.name.two = df.name.two,
  ....)

for ( i in length(my.dfs) ){
  png(file=paste(ImageDirectory,"\\", names(my.dfs)[i] ,".png",sep=""), width = 1000, height = 500)

  survival_model <- Surv(time = my.dfs[i]$LOS, event = my.dfs[i]$isTermed)
  fit <- survfit(survival_model ~ rResult, data = df)
  ggsurvplot(fit, ....)

  dev.off()
}
```

You may further consider using a function from the apply family and move the modelling and plotting logic into functions.

I hope this helps!